# How do I fix Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to work properly with UEFI BIOS Power Management (PME)?

Tags: uefi, shutdown, reboot, wakeonlan

Good morning.

I have an ASUS motherboard: F2A55-M v1.02 and it is running the most recent BIOS from the manufacturer: 6603.
I use the computer as a media server and want to be able to remotely wake the computer up.

To enable WOL I have done the following.

1.) Enabled Power On By PME in the BIOS which is needed for WOL to work.

2.) Confirmed the onboard NIC is eth0.  Through ethtool verified it "support Wake-on: pumbg" and is set to "Wake-on: g"

3.) I have run the command "sudo ethtool -s eth0 wol g" and made sure it is run on boot.

After doing so the computer when being shutdown will reboot!

If I disable Power on By PME in the BIOS the reboot on shutdown issues goes away but then I cannot use WOL.  I have tried updating the Linux kernel from 3.16 all the way up to 4.0. Same result for all linux kernels.

To confirm this is a linux problem I installed Windows 8.1 and it was fine.  Computer shutdown works correctly (does not reboot) and I am able to wake the computer remotely.

Any advice you can provide is greatly appreciated.